# Adding subviews to a view from inside another object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have these two properties defined in my appDelegate:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView * mainView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyCustomClass * customObj
```

What is the best way of adding subviews to `mainView` from code inside `customObj`?

I am not providing any sample code because (a) my code is terrible and (b) I just want to understand the best approach of doing this, so I can learn from this in the future, rather than having one solution to one specific problem.

Many thanks.

Comment: Explain it better + give some solution you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of class MyCustomClass is. Is it responsible for building mainView's view hierarchy? Then I'd inject a reference of mainView to customObj, like this:

```
customObj = [[MyCustomClass alloc] initWithView:mainView];
```

In this scenario, customObj would be some kind of builder object, that creates the view hierarchy inside mainView. Then I'd use the addSubView: selector inside MyCustomClass:

```
-(id)initWithView:(UIView*)view{
    if(self = [super init]){
        [view addSubView: ...];
        [view addSubView: ...];
        [view addSubView: ...];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

well, what about creating a method in MyCustomClass like this:

```
-(void)addSubViewToView:(UIView *)view
{
    [view addSubview:otherView];
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
[customObj addSubViewToView:mainView];
```

Comment: Or init customObj with that view - if main class creates that object.